# How to approximate

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I was reading a book and saw this approximation
$(1 - 10^{-3})^{1023} \approx 2^{-1.476}$

I am wondering how it is calculated.

Comment: If you are interested in calculation the value of $ln(2)$ leave a comment. In general any reaction to the answers would be kindful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making it more general, you wonder what is $x$ if $$(1-\epsilon)^{1023}=2^x$$ Taking logarithms, you find $$x=1023 \frac{ \log(1-\epsilon)}{\log(2)}$$ When $\epsilon$ is small, you have a very good approximation $$\log(1-\epsilon)\approx -\epsilon-\frac 12 \epsilon^2+\cdots$$ So, $$x\approx -1023\frac{\epsilon+\frac 12 \epsilon^2 }{\log(2)}$$ Ignoring the second term and using $\epsilon=10^{-3}$, we then have $$x\approx -\frac{1.023}{\log(2)}\approx -1.47588$$

Comment: The funny thing that your way is more complicated than mine. I doubt that anyone have seriously read my answer.

Comment: @callculus. I did read it and it is nice !

Comment: Thanks. I have general doubts in the voting system. But this is a discussion topic for meta.math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

@Claude Leibovici provided a nice way to solve this using the polynomial approximation for $\log(x)$, where $x$ is small. Let me give an answer that digs deeper than a polynomial approximation:

We recall a commonly accepted definition for $e$, the natural number:
$$
e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$
When we try to approximate $e$, we simply find a large number $n$, such as $1000$, and evaluate it in a formula to find $e$. For example, with $n=1000$, we get
$$
e \approx \left(1 + \frac{1}{1000}\right)^{1000} \approx 2.7169 
$$
a pretty good approximation.

Now, what if my exponent is different than the denominator inside the parentheses? Do I still get $e$? To find out, let's do some algebra.
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^m = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n \cdot \frac{m}{n}} = \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{m}{n}} \approx e^{\frac{m}{n}}
$$
Hmph. Notice that this requires $n$ to be large, but $m$ can be any value, small or large.

Now, it is also the case that
$$
e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}
$$
(notice the two sign changes). Doing the same sort of algebra gets us
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m} = \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\right)^{-\frac{m}{n}} \approx e^{-\frac{m}{n}}
$$

We can then try to apply this to your question.
$$
x := \left(1-10^{-3}\right)^{1023} = \left(1-\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{1023} \approx e^{-\frac{1023}{1000}} = e^{-1.023}
$$
We then throw in the change-of-base formula to see that
$$
\log_2 x = \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e 2} \approx \frac{-1.023}{0.693} \approx -1.476
$$

Whoa, fr$\large e \Large e \LARGE e\Huge e \LARGE e \Large e \large e$aky!

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$ we know that

$\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\approx e^{-x}$

$(1 - 10^{-3})^{1023}=(1 -\frac{1}{1000})^{1023}=(1 -\frac{1,023}{1023})^{1023}\approx e^{-1.023}$

$2^x=e^{- 1.023}$

$x=\log_2(e^{- 1.023})=\frac{-1.023}{\ln(2)}\approx-1.476$

Thus $(1 - 10^{-3})^{1023}\approx 2^{-1.476}$

Answer (score -2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\pars{1 - 10^{-3}}^{1023} \approx 2^{-1.476}:\,?.}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\pars{1 - 10^{-3}}^{1023}} & = 0.999^{1023} =
\bracks{2^{\ln\pars{0.999}/\ln\pars{2}}}^{1023} =
2^{\color{#f00}{1023\ln\pars{0.999}/\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}
$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{1023\,{\ln\pars{0.999} \over \ln\pars{2}}} = \color{#f00}{-1.476\color{#00f}{62}}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$